# How to create a coupon on specific product or category in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.

Let's say I have 20% off coupon code.
This coupon is applicable only to **Product B**

A customer have in its cart :

- Product A
- **Product B**
- Product C

I don't want my 20% off coupon apply to other product but only to Product B.

Do you know how I can do that within Magento?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shopping cart price rule under promotions.  Under conditions, you want to choose "product subselection", then under subselection add a rule that the product in the cart must match the sku of the product you want the discount to apply to.

Comment: Here is a complete walkthrough http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes#x_off_specific_products